# Docker/Reactjs/Nodejs - How to install dependencies and run application after docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize a Reactjs application with Nodejs server. In many examples, we have to install dependencies in Dockerfile but I want to do it after containers started with a script.
Is it possible to do it ?

**My docker-compose file:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web-server:
    container_name: webserver
    build:
      context: ./docker/web-server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
```

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

**My docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

[ ! -d "node_modules" ] && npm install

ls -la
npm start
```

**Container logs:**

```
total 644
drwxrwxr-x    8 node     node          4096 Oct  3 12:19 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct  3 12:19 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node             0 Oct  3 12:16 .dockerignore
drwxrwxr-x    8 node     node          4096 Oct  2 23:57 .git
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           317 Oct  2 22:23 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x    4 node     node          4096 Oct  3 12:52 .idea
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          2891 Oct  2 20:22 README.md
drwxrwxr-x    3 node     node          4096 Oct  2 23:57 docker
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           325 Oct  2 23:52 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 1020 node     node         36864 Oct  3 12:19 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node        577492 Oct  2 20:23 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           748 Oct  2 20:23 package.json
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Oct  2 20:22 public
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Oct  2 23:04 src

> docker-react@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

I want to do like that to keep the same installation logic as my Symfony API which is on another project. But my example not working.

**UPDATE 1: Now i'm trying to build my project into image but it's still not working after running** `docker-compose up -d --build`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web-server:
    container_name: webserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/web-server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: You'll get this behavior if the host bind mount already has a `node_modules` directory (try putting another `ls` before the `npm install` command to see).  General Docker best practice would be to delete the `volumes:` to use the code that's built into your image; you can use a host Node to work on the front-end (and `rm -rf node_modules; npm install; npm run start` every time if that's what you want to do).

Comment: I've tried to build the project into image without script but it's still not working. Look at my update 1 on the main post.

Comment: How isn't it working?

Comment: I have nothing when I go to `localhost:3000`. The site is not accessible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the option `stdin_open: true` in my docker-compose.yml solved the problem.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web-server:
    container_name: webserver
    build:
      context: ./docker/web-server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
    working_dir: /usr/app
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

[ ! -d "node_modules" ] && npm install

npm start
```

Now it's working for me.